# find a file with specific extension anywhere in the system

Tags: python, function, file, testing, path

I need to code a test for a function I have defined in Python 3.9. As the funtion is supposed to receive a file of a specific extension and its path, and then load it in Python, my test should look for any available file of that extension and try to load it correctly.
How can I code this?

Comment: The easiest way is to use glob (or rglob) from pathlib [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
import os
file_path = '/' # Location of files
file_extension = 'xlsx'
for i in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file_extension == i.split('.')[-1]:
        print(i)  # The task you want to perform with the specific files
```

Here `file_path` is the path of the files list, `file_extension` is the specific extension we are searching for.